# Get index of element in array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom

I has an array of objects `$('selector')`, I want to get `index()` of each element and append  it to the html of each elemt. I can get index of first element just write `$('selector').index()`, but how I can get other, and append them to they DOM-objects. Help, I am new in Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Thanks you guys, i appreciate yours help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("selector").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + " " + i);
});
```

`i` will be the index of each selected element and will be appended to the html.

Here's a jsfiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/54bcn68j/

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to the `.html()` jQuery method. This function will conveniently be called with two parameters, the element index and the current HTML, so what you want is easy:

```
$elements.html(function(i, v){
   return v + i; 
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/40mab17c/3/)

Which will give you the `index` relative to the selection made. If you wanted the index relative to each elements siblings, you would need `.index()`:

```
$('ul li').html(function(_, v){
   return v + $(this).index();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/40mab17c/2/)

Comment: @Archer Glad you think so. In fact, many jQuery methods support a function being passed to their setter versions.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that but it's something that never comes to mind.  I've not seen it used in this particular way, but I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('selector').each(function(index) {
  console.log(index);
});
```

**Example:**

Html:

```
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
<div>My Div</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div').each(function(index){
    var newHtml = $(this).html() + " - Index:" + index;
    $(this).html(newHtml);
});
```

Output:

```
My Div - Index:0
My Div - Index:1
My Div - Index:2
My Div - Index:3
My Div - Index:4
My Div - Index:5
My Div - Index:6
My Div - Index:7
My Div - Index:8
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4eomxyn/).

Answer (score 0):

Use .each() to select each element, get each index and append each index to all elements matching the selector.

```
$("selector").each(function(index) {

   var eachIndex = $(this).index();

   $(this).append(eachIndex);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.each($('selector'), function() {
    $(this)append($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eq:

```
$('selector').each(function(){
  $(this).html('index for this html is ' + $(this).eq());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should iterate using `.each`

Sample Code:

```
$("selector").each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).append(i);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just cycle through them and the iterator will tell you it's index.

```
var array = $('.someClass');
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    console.log('Element #' + i + ': ' + $(array[i]).text());
}
```